# python script running on terminal but not on local server

Tags: php, python, csv, pyaudio

Absolute path is given instead of relative one

php function to call the python script:

```
$py_script = escapeshellcmd("/home/manish/anaconda2/bin/python /opt/lampp/htdocs/frontend/master/python_features/audioAnalysis.py featureExtractionFile -i /opt/lampp/htdocs/frontend/master/uploads/rihana.wav -mw 0.5 -ms 0.5 -sw 1 -ss 1 -o /opt/lampp/htdocs/frontend/master/output/rihana_op");

exec($py_script);

Error : Error: file not found or other I/O error. (DECODING FAILED)
```

Same script runs on terminal and gives the desired output

```
manish@manish-Vostro-3446:$ /home/manish/anaconda2/bin/python /opt/lampp/htdocs/frontend/master/python_features/audioAnalysis.py featureExtractionFile -i /opt/lampp/htdocs/frontend/master/uploads/rihana.wav -mw 0.5 -ms 0.5 -sw 1 -ss 1 -o /opt/lampp/htdocs/frontend/master/output/rihana_op
Short-term CSV file: /opt/lampp/htdocs/frontend/master/output/rihana_op_st.csv saved
```

so my question is how can I execute same script via php instead of terminal

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is?

Comment: `uploads/rihana.wav`: relative path. Relative to different locations...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I have updated that relative path. Previously, I copied the wrong script.

Comment: @Shadow, I am trying to execute the script via php call instead of running it on terminal.

Comment: `escapeshellcmd(/home` => `escapeshellcmd("/home` : typo / missing quote at start?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

For others with this issue. I had the same thing but also a RunTimeWarning about not being able to find ffmpeg. Once I have installed the ffmpeg, then this error also went away.

for mac :

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

for linux:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```